# join numpy string arrays with delimiter

Tags: arrays, string, numpy, format

**1st question:** I have 2 numpy arrays of integers. I would like to create a numpy array of strings formatted as "%03d_%04d". For example, when I use

```
arr1 = np.arange(10)
arr2 = arr1**2
strarr1 = np.char.mod("%03d",arr1)
strarr2 = np.char.mod("%04d",arr2)
strarr = strarr1 + '_' + strarr2
```

I obtain

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature 
matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')
```

How can I join the two string arrays strarr1 and strarr2? And how can I join them with "_" as a separator between the two strings?

**More general question**: I have a 2D numpy array of integers of shape(10000,3). What is the simple way to create a numpy array of strings with format "%04d_%03d_%02d"?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [84]: strarr1                                                                                       
Out[84]: 
array(['000', '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008',
       '009'], dtype='<U3')
In [85]: strarr2                                                                                       
Out[85]: 
array(['0000', '0001', '0004', '0009', '0016', '0025', '0036', '0049',
       '0064', '0081'], dtype='<U4')
```

`numpy` does not implement `+` for string dtypes.  But a list comprehension does nicely (using python string add):

```
In [86]: [i+j for i,j in zip(strarr1, strarr2)]
```

or to include the '_'

```
In [88]: ['_'.join([i,j]) for i,j in zip(strarr1, strarr2)]                                            
Out[88]: 
['000_0000',
 '001_0001',
 '002_0004',
 '003_0009',
 '004_0016',
 '005_0025',
 '006_0036',
 '007_0049',
 '008_0064',
 '009_0081']
In [89]: np.array(_)                                                                                   
Out[89]: 
array(['000_0000', '001_0001', '002_0004', '003_0009', '004_0016',
       '005_0025', '006_0036', '007_0049', '008_0064', '009_0081'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

another way to use Python string add, is to 'drop down to' object dtype:

```
In [91]: strarr1.astype(object)+'_'+strarr2.astype(object)                                             
Out[91]: 
array(['000_0000', '001_0001', '002_0004', '003_0009', '004_0016',
       '005_0025', '006_0036', '007_0049', '008_0064', '009_0081'],
      dtype=object)
```

As a general rule, numpy string dtypes offer few, if any, advantages relative to python lists of strings.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj for the very useful reply!

Answer (score 1):

As a complement, the way to go in Pandas would be this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(10),
                 'B':np.arange(10)**2})
df['C']=df['A'].apply(str)+"_"+df['B'].apply(str)
```

Which give

[image]